# How "ORDER BY" ordered if they are same value?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, myisam

Let's say there's table:

```
name | score
A      100
B      98
C      99
D      99
E      99
F      98
```

and request sql = 'select * from table order by score desc'

I know order's gonna be 100, 99, 99, 99, 98, 98 but there are several values in 99 and 98.

I'm using MyIsam and want to make sure the order in the 99 and 98 is not changed even though I delete some element.
 For example, if the order was C->D->E and I delete D, then I expect to be C->E but no E->C.
Is there any logic it works when there's same order value?

Comment: There's no guarantee as to how rows with equal values are ordered; just as there is no guarantee how rows are ordered if there is no `ORDER BY` in the query. The only way to guarantee it is with a second level ordering e.g. `ORDER BY score DESC, name ASC`

Comment: You can use primary key column in second order by column to make sure the order even when you delete your row `D`.
For example: in your table if name column in primary key then your select query will be `select * from table order by score desc,name asc`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY score DESC
```

Above query ordering the data only by the score. 
If you want to order the data by another field as you mentioned, you have the add that field also to the query as below. You have mentions that you want to order by name in acceding order (C > D >E). So I used ORDER BY ASC. Below query will give you the output that you requested.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY score DESC,name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, there is no "default" ordering when `order by` keys have the same value.

Technically, this means that sorting in SQL is *unstable*.  The fix is to add one or more additional keys so each combination is unique.

For your sample data, this can presumably be handled using `name`:

```
order by score desc, name
```

You can also use any other column(s) if available that uniquely identify each row.  These keys go *after* the `score`.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite stores row in a table in an unspecified order. It means that the rows in the table may or may not be in the order that they were inserted.

If you use the  SELECT statement to query data from a table, the order of rows in the result set is unspecified. To sort the result set, you add the ORDER BY clause in the  SELECT statement as follows:

```
SELECT
   select_list
FROM
   table
ORDER BY
    column_1 ASC,
    column_2 DESC;
```

I hope this [link](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-order-by) may help you.

Comment: The question is not SQLite-tagged.